# qgis2web pop up image -- path definition

Tags: pyqgis, qgis2web, file-path

I have consulted the post on GIS stack exchange and read the docs, however I cannot find a solution that works.

The idea is to put a .png image of a site report within the maplayer for web output.  The points show up fine but the popup image does not.

The column that holds the file name for the image has been formatted in the following ways (plus many more varieties):

1. "filename.png" #<---------- images in the same folder as the project
2. "images/filename.png"#<-------- images in an images "folder" in the
       samefolder as the project
3. "../images/filename.png"

Mulitple variations on this have been tried by loading the different methods in the attribute table and having as pop up value(output from most recent try):

[image: screen shot of preview qgis2web]

The field attributes are set to photo:

[image: field attributes]

I have taken a look at the output generated by the script in the Data folder that holds the css, js and other files associated with the webpage export(in my case these files go to 'users>me>AppData>Local>Temp>qgis2web>folder'

The data is in a dictionary of dicts I put the first one here:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "field_1": "Aare_Bern_CaveltiN", "Density": 1.61, "lon_x1": 7.4733190977753496, "lat_y1": 46.923578788505381, "City": "Muri bei Bern", "File": "Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png", "FileName": "\"\\images\\Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\"", "Source": "<img source =\"\\images\\Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\" width=\"400\" height=\"600΅ \/>", "File2": "\"Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\"", "FileNameThree": "\"images\\Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\"", "FileNameFour": "<img source =\"Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\" width=\"400\" height=\"600΅ \/>", "FileNameFive": "\"<img source =\"\\images\\Aare_Bern_CaveltiN.png\" width=\"400\" height=\"600΅ \/>\"" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.47331909777535, 46.923578788505381 ] } }
```

I cannot figure out exactly what needs to be passed on to the plugin for this to work.
Nor are the examples I have found clearing this up.

Is it an absolute path or relative path?
Path to where? Although the project is one folder the output goes to temp.

Or maybe even more precise: When I call the column value from python (before exporting csv for the map layer) like this: print(df['filename'][0])

where df=layer data and filename = column that holds the files.

Should I see this: "filename.png" (in quotes) or this: filename.png (no quotes)?

Comment: I am assuming that the script is at least seeing the image because of the size of the image frame in the pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the edit widget to 'Photo', use that widget to select the images. The plugin doesn't care where the source images are, as it copies them to the export folder.

**Update**
Apologies - it lokos like you've uncovered a bug. I've opened an issue on Github, so please follow progress there: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/546

**Update 2**
I believe the issue is now fixed. If you are able, please download master branch from Github (link above) and try it out. It would be great to confirm that it is now working. Look out for qgis2web v2.28.0 in the QGIS plugins repo soon.

Comment: I am sorry, I so not see the option to select images with the widget.

Comment: Once the widget "Photo" is selected there is a pop-up window entitled :  " Edit widget properties" .  There is no file selection option.

Comment: I think Tom would say use the form to edit the feature and select the photo you want here.

Comment: Yeah, I get nothing. either way, I just tried running the absolute path "C:\...."  and once using the expression <img source="absolute path" width="400" height="600"  />

Comment: When I pass the 'img source' tag the script picks up the size values and the resulting pop up reflects that.

Comment: Ok Tom, I would love to resolve this however.  I am not familiar with the method ' Download master branch, and give it a try' .  Once I've downloaded the master branch what do I do?

Comment: OK, once you have downloaded the .zip from https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web (the green button), open the zip up, and open the folder within it called qgis2web-master. Copy all the contents. Then find the folder where qgis2web is installed - if you open the plugin manager in QGIS and select qgis2web, it will tell you the path. Open that folder, and paste the files you copied, overwriting what is there. Restart QGIS, and you should have the fix.

Comment: I've now released v2.28.0, including this fix, so you don't need to upgrade via Github. Just upgrade within QGIS.